# How to add \r\n\ in json Using c#

Tags: c#, json, http, post

I do have a hard code json,I have to send that in http request using post, 
This is the json

```
{
  "RequestHeader": {
    "UserName": " ",
    "Password": " "
  },
  "RequestBody": {
    "ChannelType": 1,
    "BillAccountNumber": "1075-001",
    "BillAccountType": null,
    "PaymentAmount": 15.05,
    "FeeAmount": 3.50,
    "ABA": "111993776",
    "BankAccount": "1234567899",
    "EmailAddress": "jonah@doe.org",
    "AccountHolder": "JonahDoe",
    "WaiveFee": false,
    "Recurring": false,
    "CustomData": null
  }
}
```

When i am passing this i am getting the right response

But when i am using the other it is not giving the response what i need, The only difference in first one my hard coded have \r\n and the 2nd one below don't have.

```
{
  "RequestHeader": {
    "UserName": " ",
    "Password": " "
    },
  "RequestBody": {
  "ChannelType": 1,
  "BillAccountNumber": "1075-001",
  "BillAccountType": null,
  "PaymentAmount": 15.05,
  "FeeAmount": 3.5,
  "ABA": "111993776",
  "BankAccount": "1234567899",
  "EmailAddress": "jonah@doe.org",
  "AccountHolder": "Jonah Doe",
  "WaiveFee": false,
  "Recurring": false,
  "CustomData": null
 }
}
```

Can some body tell me what is the problem.

Code IS:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var RequestBody = new RequestBody
        {
            ChannelType = 1,
            BillAccountNumber = "1075-001",
            BillAccountType = null,
            PaymentAmount = 15.05,
            FeeAmount = 3.50,
            ABA = "111993776",
            BankAccount = "1234567899",
            EmailAddress = "jonah@doe.org",
            AccountHolder = "Jonah Doe",
            WaiveFee = false,
            Recurring = false,
            CustomData = null
        };
        var RequestHeader = new RequestHeader
        {
            UserName = "myUname",
            Password = "MyPass"
        };
        var Request = new Request
        {
            RequestBody = RequestBody,
            RequestHeader = RequestHeader,

        };
        var ApiCredentials = new ApiCredentials
        {
            Request = Request
        };
        var httpWReq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://gw1.cwplab.com/api/Gateway/AuthorizeCheck");
        httpWReq.ContentType = "application/json";
        //httpWReq.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(" ", " ");
        string data = "{\r\n\"RequestHeader\":{\r\n\"UserName\":\" \",\r\n\"Password\":\" \"\r\n},\r\n\"RequestBody\":{\r\n    \"ChannelType\":1,\r\n    \"BillAccountNumber\":\"1075-001\",\r\n    \"BillAccountType\":null,\r\n    \"PaymentAmount\":15.05,\r\n    \"FeeAmount\":3.50,\r\n    \"ABA\":\"111993776\",\r\n    \"BankAccount\":\"1234567899\",\r\n    \"EmailAddress\":\"jonah@doe.org\",\r\n    \"AccountHolder\":\"Jonah Doe\",\r\n    \"WaiveFee\":false,\r\n    \"Recurring\":false,\r\n    \"CustomData\":null\r\n}\r\n}\r\n";//Request.ToJSON();
        string data1 = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Request);
        httpWReq.ContentLength = data.Length;
        httpWReq.Method = "POST";
        using (StreamWriter stream = new StreamWriter(httpWReq.GetRequestStream()))
        {
            stream.Write(data);
            //stream.Flush();
            //stream.Close();
        };
        dynamic httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWReq.GetResponse();
        using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            var result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
            Console.WriteLine(result);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: both the json are same.

Comment: @AmitKumarGhosh No they are not, different values

Answer (score 0):

There is a difference in the JSON. I suspect your server doesn't accept the second json (you say you get the wrong response). `\r\n` are not mandatory, it is just for the reader.

```
    "FeeAmount": 3.5,
    "FeeAmount": 3.50,
```

And

```
    "AccountHolder": "Jonah Doe",
    "AccountHolder": "JonahDoe",
```

Comment: the second one is just a `string`. Does that make any difference

Comment: Depends on what the server does with the data. For example if the server cannot find the name "JonahDoe" it will probably fail.

Comment: Thanks  RvdK and Amit ! I already find it out, But anyways thank you for your time and work.